# Understanding output of iptables -L, ip rule show (policy based routing), and ip route with multiple tables

Tags: iptables, routing, android, iproute

I'm looking for is a good explanation of how to interpret the output of `iptables -L` and `ip rule show` in conjunction with the `ip route show table <table_name>` commands.

I am struggling to understand the overly complicated policy-based routing of my OnePlus 8 Pro while the WiFi hotspot service is turned on. I have CCNA and Cisco Certified Specialist - Enterprise Core certifications, so I'm not clueless when it comes to routing and policy-based routing, but I still need help.

I don't understand much about Linux's `iptables`. I understand some of the output of `ip rule show` (like the priority and which routing table is checked if the rule is matched). I have a firm grasp on `ip route` when using a single table, but less so when combined with policy-based routing.

Unfortunately, my OnePlus 8 Pro seems to be combining iptables with policy-based routing and multiple routing tables for really no good reason at all. My system is rooted and I have busybox installed to give me most Linux standard command-line tools.

So here is the mess that I'm trying to understand:

First, here are the interfaces listed for the device:

```
OnePlus8Pro# ifconfig
dummy0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ae:22:9c:ac:69:85
          inet6 addr: fe80::ac22:9cff:feac:6985/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 TX bytes:15971

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:4f:ee:96:b3:ed  Driver cnss_pci
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3000
          RX bytes:0 TX bytes:0

rmnet_data3 Link encap:UNSPEC
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00e:387b:f22e:c336/64 Scope: Link
          inet6 addr: 2607:fc20:1bc3:a194:a00e:387b:f22e:c336/64 Scope: Global
          UP RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:804 TX bytes:1284

rmnet_data0 Link encap:UNSPEC
          inet6 addr: fe80::11c2:944d:89dd:e766/64 Scope: Link
          UP RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:51 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:7720 TX bytes:2487

rmnet_mhi0 Link encap:UNSPEC    Driver mhi_netdev
          UP RUNNING  MTU:65535  Metric:1
          RX packets:48471 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:42815 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:23427476 TX bytes:11997668

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope: Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:59 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:59 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5850 TX bytes:5850

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 62:59:38:18:bc:69  Driver cnss_pci
          inet addr:192.168.42.149  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6059:38ff:fe18:bc69/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4599 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1756 errors:0 dropped:44 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3000
          RX bytes:859009 TX bytes:143474

rmnet_data2 Link encap:UNSPEC
          inet addr:33.215.218.82  Mask:255.255.255.252
          UP RUNNING  MTU:1440  Metric:1
          RX packets:30742 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35534 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:21959066 TX bytes:11141381
```

Next, here is the routing:

```
OnePlus8Pro# ip route
33.215.218.80/30 dev rmnet_data2 proto kernel scope link src 33.215.218.82
192.168.42.0/24 dev wlan1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.149
```

And now, the ip rules (policy-based routing):

```
OnePlus8Pro# ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
10000:  from all fwmark 0xc0000/0xd0000 lookup legacy_system
10500:  from all iif lo oif dummy0 uidrange 0-0 lookup dummy0
10500:  from all iif lo oif rmnet_data0 uidrange 0-0 lookup rmnet_data0
10500:  from all iif lo oif rmnet_data2 uidrange 0-0 lookup rmnet_data2
10500:  from all iif lo oif wlan1 uidrange 0-0 lookup local_network
13000:  from all fwmark 0x10063/0x1ffff iif lo lookup local_network
13000:  from all fwmark 0xd0001/0xdffff iif lo lookup rmnet_data0
13000:  from all fwmark 0x10064/0x1ffff iif lo lookup rmnet_data2
14000:  from all iif lo oif dummy0 lookup dummy0
14000:  from all fwmark 0xc0000/0xc0000 iif lo oif rmnet_data0 lookup rmnet_data0
14000:  from all iif lo oif rmnet_data2 lookup rmnet_data2
14000:  from all iif lo oif wlan1 lookup local_network
15000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0x10000 lookup legacy_system
16000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0x10000 lookup legacy_network
17000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0x10000 lookup local_network
18000:  from all iif wlan1 lookup rmnet_data2
19000:  from all fwmark 0x64/0x1ffff iif lo lookup rmnet_data2
22000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0xffff iif lo lookup rmnet_data2
32000:  from all unreachable
```

A list of all the named routing tables:

```
OnePlus8Pro# show table all | grep "table" | sed 's/.*\(table.*\)/\1/g' | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq
1014
1025
dummy0
local
local_network
rmnet_data0
rmnet_data2
```

Output of `ip route show table <table_name>` for each named routing table:

```
OnePlus8Pro# ip route show table 1014

OnePlus8Pro# ip route show table 1025

OnePlus8Pro# ip route show table dummy0
default dev dummy0 proto static scope link

OnePlus8Pro# ip route show table local
broadcast 33.215.218.80 dev rmnet_data2 proto kernel scope link src 33.215.218.82
local 33.215.218.82 dev rmnet_data2 proto kernel scope host src 33.215.218.82
broadcast 33.215.218.83 dev rmnet_data2 proto kernel scope link src 33.215.218.82
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 192.168.42.0 dev wlan1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.149
local 192.168.42.149 dev wlan1 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.42.149
broadcast 192.168.42.255 dev wlan1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.149

OnePlus8Pro# ip route show table local_network
192.168.42.0/24 dev wlan1 proto static scope link

OnePlus8Pro# ip route show table rmnet_data0

OnePlus8Pro# ip route show table rmnet_data2
default via 33.215.218.81 dev rmnet_data2 proto static mtu 1500
33.215.218.80/30 dev rmnet_data2 proto static scope link
```

And last but not least, the output of `iptables -L`:

```
OnePlus8Pro# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
bw_INPUT   all  --  anywhere             anywhere
fw_INPUT   all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
oem_fwd    all  --  anywhere             anywhere
fw_FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
bw_FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
tetherctrl_FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
nm_qti_filter_ssdp_dropper  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
oem_out    all  --  anywhere             anywhere
fw_OUTPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
st_OUTPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
bw_OUTPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain bw_FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
bw_costly_rmnet_data2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
bw_costly_rmnet_data2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain bw_INPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
bw_global_alert  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
bw_costly_rmnet_data2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0x100000/0x100000
MARK       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             MARK or 0x100000

Chain bw_OUTPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
bw_global_alert  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
bw_costly_rmnet_data2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain bw_costly_rmnet_data2 (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
bw_penalty_box  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ! quota rmnet_data2: 9223372036854775807 bytes  reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain bw_costly_shared (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
bw_penalty_box  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain bw_data_saver (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain bw_global_alert (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ! quota globalAlert: 2097152 bytes

Chain bw_happy_box (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            match bpf pinned /sys/fs/bpf/prog_netd_skfilter_whitelist_xtbpf
bw_data_saver  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain bw_penalty_box (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            match bpf pinned /sys/fs/bpf/prog_netd_skfilter_blacklist_xtbpf reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
bw_happy_box  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain fw_FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fw_INPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fw_OUTPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain nm_mdmprxy_doze_mode_skip (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain nm_mdmprxy_iface_pkt_fwder (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain nm_qti_filter_ssdp_dropper (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:1900
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:1900

Chain oem_fwd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain oem_out (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain st_OUTPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain st_clear_caught (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain st_clear_detect (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             connmark match  0x2000000/0x2000000 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             connmark match  0x1000000/0x1000000
CONNMARK   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             u32 "0x0>>0x16&0x3c@0xc>>0x1a&0x3c@0x0&0xffff0000=0x16030000&&0x0>>0x16&0x3c@0xc>>0x1a&0x3c@0x4&0xff0000=0x10000" CONNMARK or 0x1000000
CONNMARK   udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             u32 "0x0>>0x16&0x3c@0x8&0xffff0000=0x16fe0000&&0x0>>0x16&0x3c@0x14&0xff0000=0x10000" CONNMARK or 0x1000000
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             connmark match  0x1000000/0x1000000
st_clear_caught  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state ESTABLISHED u32 "0x0>>0x16&0x3c@0xc>>0x1a&0x3c@0x0&0x0=0x0"
st_clear_caught  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain st_penalty_log (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
CONNMARK   all  --  anywhere             anywhere             CONNMARK or 0x1000000
NFLOG      all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain st_penalty_reject (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
CONNMARK   all  --  anywhere             anywhere             CONNMARK or 0x2000000
NFLOG      all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain tetherctrl_FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
bw_global_alert  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
tetherctrl_counters  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]  state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
tetherctrl_counters  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain tetherctrl_counters (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I'm trying to process/understand all these rules the same way the phone does, and I'm lost. I can't find a good explanation of lines like `10500:  from all iif lo oif rmnet_data0 uidrange 0-0 lookup rmnet_data0` in `ip rules show`. I also don't understand the marking in iptables and how to know how it applies in lines like `13000:  from all fwmark 0xd0001/0xdffff iif lo lookup rmnet_data0`.

My ultimate goal is to write a shell script that will fix the broken mess that is the WiFi Hotspot routing on this phone. I plan to launch the script after I start up the WiFi Hotspot each time. However, in order to do that, I need to understand what this routing mess is doing first.

I provided all of the output that I believe is relevant to understanding the routing here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're looking at `iptables -L`, it's missing the columns that indicate if a particular rule applies to a specific interface only. I recommend `iptables -L -vn` to see the complete definition of each iptables rule.

Comment: My own advice on this is to never use `iptables -L`  or similar (`-v` is mandatory for some usefulness anyway) but use instead `iptables-save -c` or multiple `iptables -S` which have an output in the same format as the command you'd type to add rules in the first place. Using `iptables -L` requires to learn twice how to use iptables.

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/241910/218526

Answer (score 2):

Fairly late on the party here, but. It's pretty difficult to make sense of Android routing without looking at AOSP code, which will help you cast light on a lot of this. You could figure out *what* it does, but *why* it does it would be really difficult. Android has much more complicated rules than a regular unix machine because it's typically connected to many networks at the same time ; some processes have access to some networks while others don't ; each UID might have a different default network ; apps can request another network than their default by using a number of [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network#openConnection(java.net.URL)). A unix server or desktop machine doesn't have any of this complexity to deal with, and can get by with much simpler routing.

If you're interested in how rules work, start [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/heads/master/server/RouteController.h) for the latest code (you can look back to older branches for the specific version of Android that you're interested in). Device manufacturers may have (and often have) changes on top of that, so details may vary on any specific device.

Generally the idea is that routing starts by looking at each rule in priority order (lower first). If the packet matches the rule, then the kernel will lookup the associated table ; if it finds the destination in there, that's where it sends the packet, otherwise it goes back and evaluates the next rule.

A rule like

```
10500:  from all iif lo oif rmnet_data0 uidrange 0-0 lookup rmnet_data0
```

is described in man ip-rule. In a nutshell :

- `10500` is the priority. The routing evaluates the rules in increasing order. Two rules with the same priority have undefined order.
- `from all iif lo oif rmnet_data0 uidrange 0-0` are filters. Each of them is two words :

  - `from all` means any source will match
  - `iif lo` (for input interface local) matches only traffic generated locally (not forwarded traffic)
  - `oif rmnet_data0` (for output interface) matches only traffic destined for the `rmnet_data0` interface
  - `uidrange 0-0` matches only the traffic coming from a UID comprised between 0 and 0 (so only UID 0 in this case). Android has a different UID for each app.
- `lookup rmnet_data0` simply means that if the packet matches all the filters, then you should lookup table rmnet_data0 to try and find the route. If there's one, follow it, otherwise go to the next rule.

As for the marking, [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/heads/master/include/Fwmark.h) is where you want to start. Android uses the firewall mark to manage network permissions and explicit asks from apps. As you can see in the code, the bottom 16 bits in the firewall mark are the ID of the network (Android assigns a 16-bits network ID to each network). Upper bits are used for permissions, accounting...

When you see a filter like `fwmark 0xd0001/0xdffff`, this means to mask the mark on the socket with the right part (0xdffff here) and compare it to the left part (0xd0001 here). In this case, looking up that code again, 0xdffff will keep bits 0~15 (the netId), bit 16 ("explicitly selected") and bits 18 and 19 (permissions). After that masking, traffic with a socket mark of 0xd0001 will match this rule, so it must be bound for network with netId 1, explicitly selected (which means the application has used some API to ask for this network rather than the default), it must have both permission bits (so it must be a privileged app that holds the android `USE_RESTRICTED_NETWORKS` permission).

As for how the socket gets marked, this is yet another story, but to keep it short Android uses hooks in syscalls to ship the socket to the (Android-only) netd daemon when you call `connect` or some Android API that lets you select a network, and netd will mark that socket for you. You can see the logic [in this code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/heads/master/server/FwmarkServer.cpp) if you're interested in the details. There are also some iptables rules to mark accepted sockets and a host of technical details that you can lookup in the code if you want to learn more.

Hope this helps,